# Write permission nginx gunicorn

Tags: django, docker, nginx, permissions, gunicorn

In my django/python code I have the following lines:

```
f = open(os.path.join(DIRECTORY, filname), 'w')
f.write(filecontent)
f.close()
```

when I have `DIRECTORY='/tmp/'` it all works fine, the file.txt is saved with `owner=root` and `group=www-data`. However, when I want to save the file in a subdirectory of my django-project, for example `DIRECTORY='/project/subfolder'` the file doesn't appear, although I have that subfolder set to the same owner/group.

I suspect that it is a permission problem with nginx or gunicorn. Any suggestions?

I tried to solve my problem by just mounting the `/tmp/` directory to the docker container where I use the file afterwards. But I ran into the problem, that files in the `/tmp/` directory do not appear in docker, while as when I mount another folder like `/project/subfolder/`, these files do appear in docker. So either way, half works, but never both.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what kind of permissions your subfolder has?

I also tried saving some files in my project subdirectory.
For example i had a "log" subfolder in my project folder and i had to change permissions using:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/test/myproject/log
```

**Update:**
Because of your relative path, django can't save it. You must specify the absolute path.
Therefore in you settings create a variable:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

This is the absolute path location to you project.
You have to import BASE_DIR to your py file and than you can use it like before:

```
f = open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, filname), 'w')
f.write(filecontent)
f.close()
```

Comment: checket that, as stated above, same owner/group as the one that can create the file in the `/tmp/` folder. your suggestion didn't work for me, unfortunately. I even tried `chmod 777` on the folder in consideration. but that also didn't help.

Comment: ok, can you provide the nginx error logs? normaly if it was an nginx problem there should be some there.

Comment: I was able to locate the trouble line: `f = open(os.path.join(DIRECTORY, filname), 'w')`. Locally, that works. With gunicorn/nginx it doesn't, unless I hardcode the file and location, like `f = open('/home/ubuntu/myproject/subfolder/file.txt', 'w')`, then it works... How is this possible?

Comment: aaahaa, okei now this gives a little more input on your problem. Django tries is to save the file in the excact location you entered, to let it work it will need the absolute path, not a relative. I updated my solution, this should work now.

Comment: I just found another solution that works: when I put the directory into a `str()` command, like `f = open(os.path.join(str(DIRECTORY), filname), 'w')`, it does also work...

Comment: okei? Is your "DIRECTORY" not a string?